# transform bottom border on hover the outer div with css

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, transition, onhover

i tried now for a long time to get this to work. the "line" under "Mehr erfahren" should go from 0% to 100% but i goes from 100% to 0%. Can anyone find the mistake?

```css
/* DEBUG */
.lwb-col {
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
}
.lwb-col:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 15px 30px -4px rgba(136, 155, 166, 0.4);
 
}


.lwb-col--link {
   font-weight: 500;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.lwb-col--link::after{
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    bottom: -3px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #E5E9EC;
}
.lwb-col:hover .lwb-col--link::after {
    border-color: #57B0FB;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left center;
}
```

```html
<div class="lwb-col">
  <h2>Webdesign</h2>
  <p>Steigern Sie Ihre Bekanntheit im Web mit individuellem &amp; professionellem Webdesign. Organisierte Codestruktur, sowie perfekte SEO Optimierung und jahrelange Erfahrung sprechen für uns.</p>
<span class="lwb-col--link">Mehr erfahren</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: I moved the `border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E9EC;` to `.lwb-col--link`, add a `border-bottom: 2px solid #57B0FB;` to `.lwb-col:hover .lwb-col--link::after` and use the `transform` property on the normal and hover. It works, but the border-bottom inital, doesn't disappear, it's just override.

```css
/* DEBUG */
.lwb-col {
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
}
.lwb-col:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 15px 30px -4px rgba(136, 155, 166, 0.4);
}

.lwb-col--link {
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E9EC;
}
.lwb-col--link::after{
    bottom: -3px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #E5E9EC;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}

.lwb-col:hover .lwb-col--link::after {
    border-color: #57B0FB;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #57B0FB;
}
```

```html
<div class="lwb-col">
  <h2>Webdesign</h2>
  <p>Steigern Sie Ihre Bekanntheit im Web mit individuellem &amp; professionellem Webdesign. Organisierte Codestruktur, sowie perfekte SEO Optimierung und jahrelange Erfahrung sprechen für uns.</p>
<span class="lwb-col--link">Mehr erfahren</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `transform: scaleX(0);` to the default state.

Add `transform: scaleX(1);` to the hover state.

```css
/* DEBUG */
.lwb-col {
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
}
.lwb-col:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 15px 30px -4px rgba(136, 155, 166, 0.4);
 
}


.lwb-col--link {
   font-weight: 500;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.lwb-col--link::after{
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    bottom: -3px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #E5E9EC;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}
.lwb-col:hover .lwb-col--link::after {
    border-color: #57B0FB;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left center;
}
```

```html
<div class="lwb-col">
  <h2>Webdesign</h2>
  <p>Steigern Sie Ihre Bekanntheit im Web mit individuellem &amp; professionellem Webdesign. Organisierte Codestruktur, sowie perfekte SEO Optimierung und jahrelange Erfahrung sprechen für uns.</p>
<span class="lwb-col--link">Mehr erfahren</span>
</div>
```

Comment: when i add transform: scaleX(0) to the default state the border dissappears, but the "grey" border should be shown before hover